# Are records in a PST file stored in as contiguous blocks?

Tags: outlook, msg, pst

Let's assume a PST with the following structure:

Inbox:

- msg1
- msg2

Draft:

- msg3
- msg4

can I assume that msg1 & msg2 are stored next to each other and msg3 & msg4 are stored next to each other?

Comment: I'm already reading the spec, I just haven't been able to prove or disprove the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot assume that - PST provider reuses free blocks.

Comment: Thanks! Can I assume that each email sits in one block?  Or can an email span multiple-blocks.

Comment: It can span multiple blocks.